# Поясните код из JavaScript (про localStorage)

Tags: javascript, html

В общем нужно записать отмеченные чекбоксыы (для отображения после перезагрузки). 
В интернете нашел решение, но не могу понять код (в основном синтаксис). 
Вот сам код:

```js
function save_checkbox(name)
{
    localStorage[name] = document.getElementById(name).checked ? 1 : 0
}
function load_checkbox()
{
    var table = document.getElementById('resources')
    var input = table.getElementsByTagName('input')
 
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        var checkbox = input[i]
        checkbox.checked = parseInt(localStorage[checkbox.id], 10)
    }
}
```

Можете объяснить на пальцах, как тут все работает?
В частности, что значат фигурные скобки после localStorage, ведь это не массив и не коллекция?

Comment: localStorage — это объект, а к свойствам любого объекта можно получить доступ через `[]`, где в скобках прописывается переменная или выражение, содержащее название нужного свойства. Это работает с любыми объектами: например, `document.getElementById` это то же самое, что и `document['getElementById']` и то же самое, что и `var k = 'getElementById'; document[k]`

Answer (score 1):

```
function save_checkbox(name)
{
    // в localStorage создаётся/перезаписывается item с именем, 
    // которое передаётся в качестве аргумента функции, и в него 
    // записывается состояние чекбокса, т.е. 1 если он checked, 
    // 0 если нет.
    localStorage[name] = document.getElementById(name).checked ? 1 : 0
}
function load_checkbox()
{
    // table - переменная с эл-том у которого id = resources
    var table = document.getElementById('resources')
    // input - в переменную записываются все <input /> эл-ты страницы
    var input = table.getElementsByTagName('input')
    // цикл для перебора эл-тов с переменной input
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        // в переменную checkbox записывается input текущей итерации цикла
        var checkbox = input[i]
        // ранее созданной переменной (в которой находится текущий чекбокс)
        // устанавливается значение атрибута checked, который берётся с
        // localStogare (localStorage[checkbox.id]) по id текущего 
        // эл-та (checkbox.id) используя десятичную систему счисления,
        // второй аргумент в parseInt - указание системы исчисления
        checkbox.checked = parseInt(localStorage[checkbox.id], 10)
    }
}
```